# Maximal entropy distribution with given conditionals

Tags: conditional-probability, marginal-distribution, maximum-entropy

It is well known that of all the joint distributions $p(x,y)$ with fixed marginals $p(x),p(y)$, the one with the highest entropy is:
$$
p(x,y)=p(x)p(y).
$$

Suppose instead that we have conditionals. Namely:

> Which probability distribution $p(x,y,z)$, with fixed $p(x|y)$ and $p(x|z)$, has maximal entropy?

is there even an explicit formula?

(Note: one is tempted to take $p(x,y,z)$ such that $p(x|y,z)=p(x|y)p(x|z)$, but I think this is misleading, right?)

Feel free to edit question and tags appropriately.

Comment: Crossposting this to MO.

Comment: The duplicate is answered at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211147/maximal-entropy-distribution-with-given-conditionals